# How to leave only rows from 100 to 1000 for the given table?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table

Consider a table

```
tab=Table[{i^0.333},{i,1,10000,1}];
```

How to leave only rows from 100 to 1000 in a simple way?

The brute-force approach is

```
tableft=Table[tab[[i]],{i,100,1000,1}];
```

Maybe the question is stupid, but I cannot find the answer in Documentation.

Comment: See `Part` and `Span` for `tab[[100;;1000]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [Take](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html)

```
tableft = Take[tab,{100,1000}]
```

gives elements 100 through 1000 of tab.